# I have an object that will be instantiated the entire duration of the program, but a class member that will not, should I dynamically allocate it?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, menu

Let me flush out my question a bit more:

I have a Game class that is instantiated at the beginning of the program and is destroyed only at the end of the program's lifetime.

I have a "StartMenu" member object within my Game class that I clearly want to be available at the beginning of the game's lifetime, but that *shouln't* be taking up memory after the user starts the game.  (There is simply no reason for it to).

My current solution is to declare a StartMenu pointer as a member, dynamically allocate memory to it by a method called from the constructor, (or elsewhere if necessary) and then **delete** it when the user wished to play the game.  Is this a good practice solution? Should the design be changed, or  is there or more standard way "Start Menus" are handled?

Relevant Code:

```
Class Game 
{
  private:
  StartMenu* startMenu_ptr;

  //Other  Game Vars
}
```

Initializing

```
Game::initStartMenu() {
  startMenu_ptr = new StartMenu(); 
}
```

Deleting

```
Game::runStartMenu() {

if(startMenu_ptr->getOption()==1) {
  delete startMenu_ptr;
  startMenu_ptr = nullptr;
}
```

EDIT: More details are necessary. runStartMenu is called from a while loop every frame to detect updates and user input. Moreover, any updates to startMenu are recorded and then drawn in a separate method (Game::render()) to reflect user input. I cannot be reInitializing startMenu at every iteration of the loop.

Game::update() (Called from main, inside event while loop)

```
void Game::update() {

switch(gameState)
 {
  case 0:
       runStartMenu();
       break;
  case *n*... //other game screens...
 }
}
```

And then my draw Game::render() function: (Called from main, inside event while loop)

```
Game::render()

  switch(gameState)
   {
    case 0:
       drawStartMenu();
       break;
    case *n*... //other game screens...
   }
  }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT : as requested, allow background execution of other tasks while the menu is running**

As a general rule, you should never manipulate raw `new` and `delete` operators outside the context of smart pointers. For your use case, you can absolutely use static allocation and dynamic allocation doesn't bring any advantage, so I suggest you design it in a straightforward manner like so :

```
StartMenu::choice_t choice;

Game::runStartMenu() {
    auto menuThread = std::thread([](){
        auto menu = StartMenu{/* options */};
        // for example :
        choice = menu.show(); 
    }); // the menu memory gets freed here 

    
    menuThread.join(); // wait for execution end

    // choice handling logic
}
```

Then, the caller can implement menu choice logic and start the game !

Comment: You're assuming the start menu can run standalone. This is frequently not the case.

Comment: What does it depend on ? Your question does not reflect this. I'm not really sure what you mean, can you give an example ?

Comment: There can be a lot of background activity going on while the start menu is displayed. You're assuming there is none of this activity, or that the start menu provides all of the event handling to drive it.

Comment: Two possibilities : either you need to start it in a different thread from the `runStartMenu` function or the thread logic is embedded in the `StartMenu` object logic. In both cases, your solution with the pointer doesn't solve it and no background activity is possible with your design.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I will need to expand my question for this to me more helpful. The scope for my StartMenu object must be larger than the method itself, since it is drawn onto the screen in my Game::draw() method.

Comment: Updated my answer with the thread approach, hope it helps !